# Show Datagridview Rowheader Tooltip

Tags: c#, datagridview

Greeting to all,

Please help me how to set back again the tooltip text of row header of datagridview, When I load the datatable and set each tooltip for rows of datagridview, its show correctly when I move mouse pointer to row header but when I click the column to sort the data to ascending or descending the tooltip for the row header was remove ? how I can set it back or to avoid it when I clicking the column header of datagridview .... thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Move the code that sets your row tooltips to the `DataBindingComplete` event handler. This handle will trigger every time the `DataSource` updates (which includes sorting). Like so:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;

private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.ToolTipText = "ToolTip Text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `ToolTipText` property on  [`DataGridViewColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.ToolTipText = "Tooltip"; // set here.
}
```